# Using a function of a class in constructor of other class

Tags: c++

I have two classes that one of those(class ode) has a private member that is a function(pointer to a function):

```
class ode 
{
private:
    double T;
    double (*sfn)(double,double,double*);//I mean this
    int Ne;

public:
    ode(double t,double (*f)(double,double,double*),int N)
    {
        Ne=N;
        T=t;
        sfn=f;
    } //.....
}
```

and now I want to construct an ode object that in its construction the function(sfn) should take from another class!! If i want to use a function that is out of any classes, i should just write name of that function in the constructor.But this situation is different.
What can i do?? how i can construct this object??

Comment: You can't pass non static class member functions using this signature. Also instead of function pointers, it's better to define an interface, and pass a reference to that one.

Comment: Another tip: Use `std::function` it will work for plain functions and class member functions.

Comment: Remember that member functions operate using the data from an object of the class to which they are members. They don't make much sense being called without their class data. You can declare *member function pointers* but they are typed to the class they are member of and need an object of that type in order to invoke them.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to call a member function requires a pointer to the class.

```
class X {
   ...
   double fn( double,double,double*);
};
```

To be able to get a pointer to member, you need an idea such as this.

```
X * pMember; // hold instance we want to call.
typedef double (X::*funcPointer)( double, double, double * );
funcPointer fPtr = X::fn;
```

Then finally can be called with

```
(pMember->*fPtr)( v1,v2,&v3);
```

In all cases, the class of X needs to be known.

The reason to use this pattern, is when there are multiple functions which share a signature, which are used for different reasons.  UI systems (MFC, wxWidgets) use this technique to bind a window event to a handler function.

Alternatively, use multiple inheritance, where the function is well defined, but the implementation is different for implementations.

```
 class base {
      virtual double func( double, double, double * ) = 0;
 };
 class X1 : public base {
     double func( double, double, double * )
     {
        // implementation.
     }
 };

 class X2 : public base {
     double func( double, double, double * )
     {
        // implementation.
     }
 };
```

Each implementation X1, X2, ... delivers the changed behavior suitable for virtual binding.

This just requires a member to base;

```
 base * pBase;
 pBase->func( v1, v2, &v3);
```